# Render Report an internal error occurred: Failed to generate the PMD 4.x report in eclipse mars

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

I'm new in using PMD. I configured PMD 4.x version plugin in eclipse mars 4.x.

I've tried to generate an XML report by right-clicking the project > PMD> Generate Reports

After which this error dialog box appears.

An internal error occurred during: "RenderReport". "Compilation unit name must end with .java, or one of the registered Java-like extensions”?

Can someone help me? Why can't I generate report in PMD?